# How i can summarize totals based on a scalar value in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-summaries

I have a data frame with a column "discount" with values from 0 to 1. I want to count the rows based on grouped values for discount e.g  discount 0-0.09   xxx books, 0.1 - 0.19   xxx books, etc

```
                                             title price sPrice  discount
1                                Ανίκητοι ηττημένοι 16.31  23.30 0.3000000
2               Η πολιτική ως κάλεσμα και επάγγελμα 10.80  12.00 0.1000000
3                              Η αρπαγή της Ευρώπης  8.95  17.90 0.5000000
4                    Το τέλος του κόκκινου ανθρώπου 11.94  19.90 0.4000000
5             Εξηγώντας την Αναρχία στον μπαμπά μου 10.39  14.84 0.2998652
6                    Είναι ο καπιταλισμός, ηλίθιε..  9.90  11.00 0.1000000
7     Η τραγωδία της πολιτικής των μεγάλων δυνάμεων 25.20  36.00 0.3000000
8                       Ώρα Ελλάδος, Βουκουρέστι... 10.50  15.00 0.3000000
9  Αποικιοκρατία. Η ευρωπαϊκή επέκταση μετά το 1763  7.85  11.21 0.2997324
10                                Δόξα και αδιέξοδα  5.32  13.30 0.6000000
```

so, i want to count the books with discount from 0-0.09, 0.1-0.19 ... till 0.9-1

Comment: Please use `dput` to show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: There are a lot of questions on SO already on 1) cutting continuous variables into bins, and 2) counting observations by group. What research have you done, and what have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Well I made it using  `cut` function

```
all.books$discount<-cut(all.books$discount,breaks = seq(0,1,by=0.1),right = FALSE)
```

after that, I used the `summary(all.books$discount)` and got the results i was looking for